# connectedRouter Error: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to React.js and was setting up base project at that I was getting one issue that my routing got changed but component doesn't load. After googling I found that I need to use ConnectedRouter. While setting up ConnectedRouter, I am getting console error: **Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter, connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import loginReducer from "./store/reducers/login";
import { watchLogin} from "./store/sagas";
import { history } from '../src/shared/history';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';



import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login: loginReducer
});
const routersMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history)
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routersMiddleware];

const store = createStore(
    connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
    {},
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(watchLogin);

const app = (
    <Provider  store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter  history={history}>
            <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 113):

For the sake of helping future souls with this issue, it turns out that according to the linked github discussions, that version 5.0 of the `history` package is causing the issue and downgrading to version 4.10.1 solves the problem for me.

```
npm install history@4.10.1
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/803

https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804

Comment: Absolute legend! I've started working on a fresh project. Been trying to figure why exact same code from older projects wouldn't work with this one. Thanks a lot for ending this miserable debugging session of mine!

Comment: thanks alot, also i need to append this if you are using docker , restart the container in case of downgrade :)))

Comment: Thank you! Would never have found this in a zillion years.

Comment: So grateful for this answer. I was beginning to think I needed to remove redux from my app in order to fix.

Comment: Gosh, I wish I stumbled upon this answer earlier... THANK YOU! Here, take my upvote!

Answer (score 22):

The main issue is the version of the history package, with react-router-dom v5 you need to use history v4 (the latest version of which is 4.10.1) - history v5 is only compatible with react-router-dom v6.

Comment: You saved my day. Is there a doc saying that in any of those packages?

Answer (score 20):

Add `router` in your reducer with using `connectRouter` and `history`

Refer this link

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/connected-react-router

```
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  login: loginReducer,
  router: connectRouter(history),
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You have forgotten :

```js
router: connectRouter(history),
```

in your combineReducers()

Answer (score 5):

If you use `immutable` you should import `ConnectedRouter` from 'connected-react-router/immutable'.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.
I forgot to give the history as a parameter to my rootReducer, in my store initialization.

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer(history), // <-- HERE
  {},
  ...
)
```